# How to select bean to inject at runtime

Tags: jakarta-ee, ejb, cdi

I'm trying to find a way to choose between several EJBs to inject at runtime.

The scenario goes like this:
There are i.e. 2 beans (ejbA, ejbB) which all implement the same interface (ejbInterface). At several injection points (other managed beans, i.e. in ejbCaller bean) I want to inject an implementation of ejbInterface. I will know which one I need at runtime (i.e. based on some DB value).

I know that one working way to do this is by making the selection at deployment via @Alternative annotation and deployment descriptors but I'd rather make the choice at runtime.

I already tried the @Producer approach but this way I can only inject unmanaged objects (objects I instantiate in the producer and that are not container managed or can be themselves injection points). I have found two workarounds/exploits of producer:

- Produce an un-managed object and pass any managed object (i.e. other beans, entity managers) via a `setup` method in ejbInterface (ejbCaller will have to pass these)
- Use a JNDI lookup in the producer and return a managed object

Both workarounds are error-prone and not elegant. Is there a better solution for this?

Comment: I'd definitely go with the second choice. Have a look at a similar situation here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12512571/jpa-inheritance-and-ejb-polymorphism

Comment: Thank you very much for the pointer! I agree that the first approach is more dangerous. I'll work on the JNDI lookup and see how well it goes.

Comment: Haven't looked at Instance from CDI?

Comment: This definitely looks more elegant for me. I'm afraid I never heard of this feature of CDI (shame on me) but I'll explore it. I suppose that if I `@Inject @Any Instance<ejbInterface> myEJBs` and inspect each element in myEJBs, I can choose the EJB to return from my producer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just inject the BeanManager and use

```
javax.enterprise.inject.spi.BeanManager.getBeans(Type, Annotation...)
```

at runtime